# Pure C, malloc void**

Tags: c, gcc

Имеется структура

```
typedef struct _prQueue
{
    void            **pv_items;       // items of heap
    size_t          n_capacity;     // heap capacity
    size_t          n_size;         // count of elements
    size_t          n_item_size;      // size of item in bytes
    int             (*itemPriorityFunc)(void *, int *);
} PrQueue;
```

Завожу под массив `pv_items` при помощи `malloc` память:

```
int prQueueCreate(
    int             (*itemPriorityFunc)(void *, size_t *),
    size_t          n_capacity,
    size_t          n_item_size,
    PrQueue         ** pp_queue
) {
    *pp_queue = malloc( sizeof( PrQueue) );

    void * p; // = (*pp_queue)->pv_items;
    p = malloc( sizeof( void** ) * n_capacity );
    (*pp_queue)->pv_items = p;
    ...
}
```

память успешно выделяется и адрес заносится в `p`.
при присвоении:

```
(*pp_queue)->pv_items = p;
```

`(*pp_queue)->pv_items` становится равным 0

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Мне кажеться, что вы пытаетесь организовать там массив, с учётом параметра `n_capacity`. Как следствие: `p = malloc( sizeof(void**) * n_capacity );   p[0] = malloc( sizeof( PrQueue));...итд ` второй цикл выделения производить например через `for (i = 0; i < n_capacity; i++) { p[i] = .. }`

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете, т.е. описываете какое-то магические поведение, которого на самом деле не бывает. Ничего подобного в данном коде происходить не может. Неточности в коде есть, но вызвать такой эффект они не могут. Не надо приводить здесь выдуманный код "по мотивам". Приводите что-то более-менее реальное.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc( sizeof( pp_queue ) )` - выделяется память под указатель `PrQueue  **`. Присвоение `(*pp_queue)->pv_items = p;` портит память. Вы хотели выделить память под объект, тогда нужно `sizeof(PrQueue)` или `sizeof( **pp_queue )`.

Comment: Нет, я исправил это, дело не в этом совсем.